Expo and nativewind throw warning for border radius
I am using expo and nativewind. I used the border radius top to create a rounded effect and used a value of 70. I didn't used px or other value, because I know native does not support px.
<View className="bg-white/50 mt-16 p-5 rounded-t-[50] h-full">

I also tried to setup the style basic using style and borderTopLeftRadius: 50 to setup values. But no matter what I try, i get the following warnings in the console.
OS Bundled 10344ms (node_modules/expo-router/entry.js)
iOS Bundled 10310ms (node_modules/expo-router/entry.js)
Android Bundled 10238ms (node_modules/expo-router/entry.js)
transform[stderr]: Expected style "borderTopLeftRadius: 50" to contain units
transform[stderr]: Expected style "borderTopRightRadius: 50" to contain units
transform[stderr]: Expected style "borderTopLeftRadius: 50" to contain units
transform[stderr]: Expected style "borderTopRightRadius: 50" to contain units

I tried to setup the basic style of radius, I tried using rounded-xl or other values, but I always get the error in the console...
